# How to implement Copy to ClipBoard (Trigger Windows Ctrl+C Event) functionality?

Tags: jquery

I need to implement a Copy to ClipBoard functionality in my screen

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).on("click", "#inputbtn", function () {

var text = $("#comment").val();





    });

</script>
</head>
<body>

Enter Comment: <input type="text" id="comment"><br> </br>

 <input type="button" id = "inputbtn" value="Copy It ClipBoard">

</body>
</html>
```

Not having any idea how to continue further on this

I have seen this link

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3458851

which isn't working in Chrome

Is this can be done without using any plugins

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Requires a third-party plug-in, like Flash, to work cross-platform.

Comment: @SterlingArcher ya seen that so thats the reason i have putup without using any plugins in my question